# How can I make an indicator function with Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

I'm looking to create a simple indicator variable in Pyomo. Assuming I have a variable x, this indicator function would take the value 1 if x > 0, and 0 otherwise.

Here's how I've tried to do it:

```
model = ConcreteModel()  
model.A = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
model.B = Set(initialize=['J', 'K'])

model.x = Var(model.A, model.B, domain = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.ix = Var(model.A, model.B, domain = Binary)

def ix_indicator_rule(model, a, b):
    return model.ix[a, b] == int(model.x[a, b] > 0)

model.ix_constraint = Constraint(model.A, model.B,
                             rule = ix_indicator_rule)
```

The error message I get is along the lines of `Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions`, which according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171498/finding-pyomo-provided-math-functions) are found at `pyomo.environ`...but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using `validate_PositiveValues()`, like this:

```
def ix_indicator_rule(model, a, b):
    return model.ix[a, b] == validate_PositiveValues(model.x[a, b])

model.ix_constraint = Constraint(model.A, model.B,
                             rule = ix_indicator_rule)
```

with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a "[big-M](http://www.thequestforoptimality.com/bigm-dual/)" constraint, like this:

```
model = ConcreteModel()  
model.A = Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3])
model.B = Set(initialize=['J', 'K'])

# m must be larger than largest allowed value of x, but it should
# also be as small as possible to improve numerical stability
model.m = Param(initialize=1e9)

model.x = Var(model.A, model.B, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.ix = Var(model.A, model.B, domain=Binary)

# force model.ix to be 1 if model.x > 0
def ix_indicator_rule(model, a, b):
    return model.x <= model.ix[a, b] * model.m

model.ix_constraint = Constraint(
    model.A, model.B, rule=ix_indicator_rule
)
```

But note that the big-M constraint is one-sided. In this example it forces `model.ix` on when `model.x > 0`, but doesn't force it off when `model.x == 0`. You can achieve the latter (but not the former) by flipping the inequality to `model.x >= model.ix[a, b] * model.m`. But you can't do both in the same model. Generally you just pick the version that suits your model, e.g., if setting `model.ix` to `1` worsens your objective function, then you would pick the version shown above, and the solver will take care of setting `model.ix` to `0` whenever it can.

Pyomo also offers disjunctive programming features (see [here](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling_extensions/gdp.html) and [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5492d7f4e4b00040889988bd/t/57c06ea8d482e91c235c4ab8/1472229087205/10_GDP.pdf)) which may suit your needs. And the cplex solver offers [indicator constraints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/indicator_constr/01_indicators_title_synopsis.html), but I don't know whether Pyomo supports them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Piecewise function and doing something like this:

```
DOMAIN_PTS = [0,0,1,1000000000]
RANGE_PTS  = [0,0,1,1]
model.ix_constraint = Piecewise(
     model.A, model.B,
     model.ix, model.x,
     pw_pts=DOMAIN_PTS,
     pw_repn='INC',
     pw_constr_type = 'EQ',
     f_rule = RANGE_PTS,
     unbounded_domain_var = True)

def objective_rule(model):
    return sum(model.ix[a,b] for a in model.A for b in model.B)

model.objective = Objective(rule = objective_rule, sense=minimize)
```

It seems to work okay.