# How to solve nonlinear inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am new in optimisation problem. In my optimisation problem, I have one binary variable `y` and one integer variable `n`.

I have L: `L= b*c*y`
Where b, c are parameters.
and the constraint is: `L/n<1` (which means L over n). I can also consider `L<n`. Another constraint in my problem is: I need that if `L==0` then `n=0` (`n` should be equal to 0, too). Moreover, `L` and `N` are always non-negative.

How can I linearise these constraints? Is it possible?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `L<n`?

Comment: Is `L` always non-negative in your case?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yes, L is always nonnegative.

Comment: if `b*c` is positive then if y = 0 => L = 0 => n = 0, (0,0) is one solution.
if y = 1 => L > 0 => (1, [L]+1..inf) other solutions. 
It does not look like a coding issue. The problem is rather math problem to be solved in mind.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento I am using Pyomo. The problem is that L includes decision variable and I cannot use **if statement** in Pyomo which includes variable in the constraint. So I think I have to linearize it but I am new in these problems and I dont know how I should solve it.

Comment: I see only 2 vars y and n. I do not understand what do you mean by *decision variable*, a decision variable in optimization is any variable that comes from the real world and does not synthetically introduce by technical reasons. And I do not see why do you need pyomo here. And even if you use pyomo it will give you only one point, not the whole solution to your problem.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento I asked about only a part of my problem here. The problem is big and it has more variables (n and y are array of variable such as y[i] and n[k] in my original problem) So I need to use solver.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995476/how-can-i-make-an-indicator-function-with-pyomo) could be useful.

Comment: To linearize the second statement you may add constraints like 100500*L >= n. 
Or, if  L turns to zero only if y=0 (like you show), y >= n/100500 probably would be better for the solver. 
You need to guess the 100500 constant from the problem statement. That constant is the upper bound (maybe not strict, anyone suites, but the tighter the better) for `n` values. It is usually not very difficult from a complete statement. 
Yet it is impossible from your bit of problem because there is nothing that keeps n limited.